# Error when using OR in where clause

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to performa query in sequelize using the or operator according to the documentation [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/).

```
m.client_state.find({
    where: {
        validUntil: {
            $or: {
                lt: Date.now(),
                eq: null
            }
        }
    }
```

This looks correct to me according to the documentation. I have also tried the $and operator and doing it without the $ symbol however i always get this exception.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.module.exports.QueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1753:45)
at /home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1609:27
at /home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3159:15
at baseForOwn (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/lodash/index.js:2089:14)
at Function.<anonymous> (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3438:16)
at Object.module.exports.QueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1608:11)
at Object.module.exports.QueryGenerator.getWhereConditions (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1980:21)
at Object.module.exports.QueryGenerator.selectQuery (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1287:30)
at module.exports.QueryInterface.select (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:685:27)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:743:34)
at tryCatcher (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:454:31)
at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:530:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:182:12)
at Async._drainQueues (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:187:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/grimurd/Documents/Repos/WiFi/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/mai
```

The code works fine if i skip the $or and use just lt or eq.

Comment: It seems $or expects its argument to always be an array - even though the documentation shows using an object. Could you open a bug on the sequelize repo?

Comment: Yeah you're right, this worked after i put the object inside an array. I will create an issue on their repo.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the **$**

```
$lt: Date.now(),
$eq: null
```